# how to resolve conflict with git after autoformat in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git

We have two users working on the same class files in two separate git branches.

User A does nothing else but an "autoformat" Ctrl-Sift-F in Eclipse

User B just adds a space in a comment

Now we get a "conflicting change" and can't merge anymore.

Basically we are stuck just because of the autoformat.

How to resolve this situation in Eclipse git or on command line git bash?

Comment: Manually fix the conflicting change? EGit has a merge client that makes that easy.

Comment: How, should I use the Team synchronization Tool?

Comment: Double click on the conflict and a merge window should appear, which allows you to take changes from either side

Comment: I have started the mergetool (Mac) since otherwise I did not get the two files side by side. Now I have them side by side, the text is 100% identical, it's just differently formatted and there is total mismatch between these two sides by the tool - it gets messed up and lost because of the autoformat. There is no place I can double click. All I need is to keep just the left or the right side - it does not matter. I also don't want to select parts from the left or the right to keep since its really messed up. I just want the complete left or right side. Or can I "help" to fix the association

Comment: Teach your users not to do autoformat on code that's already been submitted to the repository. It creates unnecessary pain to people working on the code, especially when comparing versions. I don't even make trivial changes like removing trailing whitespace from lines once the code has been sent up to the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resolve the conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git?rq=1) as you would with any merge conflict. It sounds like a pretty simple conflict to resolve. Or since the changes were trivial, the person doing the merge (i.e. the person who hasn't pushed their commit) can just reset back to a common commit, allowing them to pull the other person's changes.

```
git reset --hard THECOMMITID^
```

Where `THECOMMITID` is the unwanted formatting change. If it's just the most recent commit then you can use `HEAD^`.

Comment: everything has been committed by both users A and B already. I have the code side by side with the merge tool. But there is totally wrong association between left and right even though the text is 100% identical. How can I now just keep the left OR the right? I can't just keep parts from right to left since it's totally wronly associated. Is there a way to change the association the tool makes somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git merge -s ours` or `git merge -s their` to decide which version of the file you wanna keep after the merge.

Comment: Can I do that within Eclipse easily, I prefer not to use the command line tool if possible?

Comment: Yes, you can select the file in "Package explorer" or "Navigator" and select "Replace with -> " and then select the proper commit that contains your desired version of the file.